# Rails Cucumber Testing - Send form data to method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, cucumber

**I'm trying to send form data, from cucumber test, to controller method.**

I have a form with login & password fields, and submit button.
The form View:

```
<%= text_field_tag 'login', id: 'login-input' %>
<%= password_field_tag 'password', nil, id: 'password-input' %>
<%= submit_tag 'Login', id: 'submit-credentials' %>
```

In cucumber step, I input values in that form (login fields not shown, but similar).

```
Then(/^I press "password-input"$/) do
  find("#password-input").click
end
Then(/^I enter "myPassword" into the "password-input"$/) do
  find("#password-input").text("myPassword")
end
```

So now login and password values are set. 
I then press submit button

```
And(/^I press "submit-credentials"$/) do
  find("#submit-credentials").click()
end
```

And **my authenticate method gets called** as it should, **but its parameters are empty**.

When I input values normally on the webpage, everything works fine. Why doesn't the cucumber version work?

**All my cucumber steps pass!! so im confused**

**How can I send data from textfields to controller method?**

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to [interact with forms in Capybara](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#interacting-with-forms)

Try to use

```
Then(/^I enter "myPassword" into the "password-input"$/) do
    find("#password-input").set("myPassword")
end
```

Instead of

```
Then(/^I press "password-input"$/) do
    find("#password-input").click
end
Then(/^I enter "myPassword" into the "password-input"$/) do
    find("#password-input").text("myPassword")
end
```